# Calculate the derivative of a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, math, derivative

I have the following function (Viviani's curve):

```
Phi     = @(t)[ cos(t)^2, cos(t)*sin(t), sin(t) ]
```

Just a check that it's valid:

```
s = linspace(0,T,1000);
plot3(cos(s).^2, cos(s).*sin(s), sin(s));
```

How to derivate the function `Phi` (maybe multiple times), which represents Viviani's curve in a point `t` where `t` goes from `0` to `2*pi`? Did I defined `Phi` suitable for such a derivative? I've tried `diff`, but it did not keep the `Phi` as I would need it.

If the second derivative would be `Phi_d2`, I need to get it's value (for example in `t = 0`).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you want to derive it numerical or analytical (Symbolic Math Toolbox required)? And why not by hand?

Comment: To calculate it numerically without any additional toolbox, you could use a simple finite difference (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference), e.g. `(Phi(1.1)-Phi(.9))/.2` to calculate the first order derivative in t=1.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are three ways you can accomplish this. The first uses [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html), the second uses a [`symfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html), and the third uses [complex step differentiation](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2013/10/14/complex-step-differentiation/):

```
% Using subs
syms t
Phi = [cos(t) cos(t).*sin(t) sin(t)];
Phi_d2 = diff(Phi,t)
double(subs(Phi_d2,t,0))

% Using symfun
syms t
Phi(t) = [cos(t) cos(t).*sin(t) sin(t)];
Phi_d2 = diff(Phi,t)
double(Phi_d2(0))

% Using complex step differentiation
Phi = @(t)[cos(t) cos(t).*sin(t) sin(t)];
h = 2^-28;
cdiff = @(f,x)imag(f(x(:)+1i*h))/h;
Phi_d2 = cdiff(Phi,0)
```

You can find a function for performing first- and second-order complex step differentiation [on my GitHub: `cdiff`](https://github.com/horchler/cdiff). Note that complex step differentiation won't work well for higher order derivatives. It's best when one only has a non-differentiable function or needs fast numerical first derivatives.

Comment: +1 I did not know you can do `Phi(t)=...` to make a symfun. Thanks.

Comment: @ja72: It's a slightly newer feature so old versions won't support it – I think that it was introduced with Matlab R2012a.

Comment: Must have coincided with ditching maple and taking on mupad. I thought it was an oversight you could not define arbitrary functions, but now you can with `syms f(x)` so you can symbolically evaluate things like `diff(1/f(x),x)` into `-diff(f(x),x)/f(x)^2`.

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completeness, the numerical solution without using any additional toolboxes:

```
N = 999;
t = linspace(0,2*pi,N+1);
Phi = [cos(t); cos(t).*sin(t); sin(t)];
dPhi = gradient(Phi,2*pi/N)
```

For non-uniformly spaced argument vectors, the second parameter of [`gradient`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html) is defined by a spacing vector instead of a scalar. (time or angle vector is appropriate) - in this case it is obviously necessary to split up the dimensions. (Though I don't know why.)

So alternatively, though not necessary:

```
dX = gradient(Phi(1,:),t);
dY = gradient(Phi(2,:),t);
dZ = gradient(Phi(3,:),t);
dPhi = [dX; dY; dZ];
```

Comment: The spacing parameter of `t(2)-t(1)` is required here or you'll get an incorrectly-scaled answer. By default `gradient` assumes a spacing of `1`. And I see no way of handling non-uniform time vectors as you indicate – except breaking the problem up, which might have its issues.

Comment: Also, for first derivatives, you'll find that complex step differentiation (which doesn't require any toolboxes) has significantly less error than using `gradient`.

Comment: `2*pi/N` is not the correct spacing if you're using `linspace` and want accuracy. `t(2)-t(1)` should be used as all point are spaced by that much, except possibly the last one.

Comment: @horchler: I corrected my answer. For single dimensions non-uniform spaced vectors are working. For 3 dimensions you're right its tricky, you should deal with every dimension separately. And I do Not doubt that the complex step differentiation could be more accurate, it's just not that straight forward.

Comment: I don't want to belabor it, but it's all a matter a of accuracy. Look at the actual spacing in `t`: `diff(t)`. `linspace` doesn't create points the same way as `:` notation. If you want to specify the step size that way use something like `t = 2*pi*(0:0.01:1)`, then your points will be spaced by `0.01*2*pi` (except possibly near the middle of the vector).

Comment: @horchler: Of course you're right, but it was just a "typo" - now `A = linspace(0,2*pi,N+1);` and 
`B = 0:2*pi/N:2*pi;` are equal