# Derivative of Anonymous Function

Tags: matlab

I have the following anonymous function:

```
f = @(x)x^2+2*x+1
```

I'm using this so that I use it in the following way:

```
f(0) = 1
```

But what if I want to find the derivative of such a function while still keeping it's anonymous function capability? I've tried doing the following but it doesn't work:

```
f1 = @(x)diff(f(x))
```

but this just returns

```
[]
```

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Of course I could manually do this in 3 seconds but that's not the point...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate the derivative of a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613859/calculate-the-derivative-of-a-vector)

Comment: @horchler It's similar but I don't see any answers like gaston's so I would argue in favor of keeping it.

Comment: No, the part in my answer there discussing the complex step derivative is identical. That and the code I provided there is more flexible (vectorized and allows you to pass in a function) and the complex step derivative is superior to basic finite difference.

Comment: @horchler You posted the comment too late :P, 8 seconds late to be specific. I would not have provided the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do diff of a vector of n elements it just outputs another vector of n-1 elements with the consecutive differences.. so when you put a 1 element vector you get an empty one.

A way to go would be to decide an `epsilon` and use the Newton's difference quotient:

```
epsilon = 1e-10;
f = @(x) x^2+2*x+1;
f1 = @(x) (f(x+epsilon) - f(x)) / epsilon;
```

or just do the math and write down the formula:

```
f1 = @(x) 2*x+2;
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation

Comment: Interesting. I like this. Thanks for your time!

Comment: As per [@horchler](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2278029/horchler)s answer in this [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613859/calculate-the-derivative-of-a-vector) - the complex step method is orders of magnitude more efficient than Newtons' difference quotient. As compared by [Cleve](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2013/10/14/complex-step-differentiation/#487a1d22-7fe2-446e-a2a3-69ec283c2d97). Just change the f1 line in this answer to read as follows: `f1=@(x)imag(f(x(:)+1i*espilon))/epsilon;`

Answer (score 4):

If you have symbolic math toolbox, you can use symbolic functions to achieve the desired as follows:

```
syms x
myFun=x^2+2*x+1;
f=symfun(myFun,x);
f1=symfun(diff(f),x);

%Check the values
f(2)
f1(2)
```

You should get 9 and 6 as answers.

Answer (score 2):

@jollypianoman this works to me. Actually you need to say that the symfun has to be evaluate using eval command, then you get all the features of an anonymous function. the best is to read the example below...

```
clear
N0=1;N1=5;
N=@(t) N0+N1*sin(t);
syms t
Ndot=symfun(diff(N(t)),t); 
Ndot_t=@(t) eval(Ndot);
Ndot_t(0)

ans = 5

Ndot_t(1)

ans = 2.7015

[tstop] = fsolve(Ndot_t,pi/3)
tstop =

     1.5708
```

cheers,
AP